# Javascript/css Roulette wheel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a sideways image roulette wheel. Kind of like this

http://image.prntscr.com/image/b178316bc4994229831f21109aa59555.png

I can't seem to find a source or example anywhere.

Comment: You might find [Matthew Lein's jSlots for jQuery](https://github.com/matthewlein/jQuery-jSlots) useful. [Demo here](https://matthewlein.com/experiments/slots.html).

Answer (score 0):

Basic HTML

```
`<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="" alt="" id="picture1"/>
    <img src="" alt="" id="picture2"/>
    <img src="" alt="" id="picture3"/>
    <img src="" alt="" id="picture4"/>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="spin()">click</button>
  </body>
</html>`
```

And javascript

```
function spin(){
    var x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) 
    switch (x) {
      case 0:
        document.getElementById('picture1');
        break;
      case 1:
        document.getElementById('picture2')
        break;
      case 2:
        document.getElementById('picture3')
        break;
      case 3:
        document.getElementById('picture4')
        break;
    }
  }
```

The rest is up to you friend